# How to import dart file in FlutLab?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, directory

I am unable to import login_screen.dart

it is showing error whether I use package:myapp/lib/screens/login_screen.dart

or package:myapp/screens/login_screen.dart or Auto Import URI

https://flutlab.io/root/app/lib/screens/login_screen.dart

Will anyone help me please?

[image]

Comment: `import 'package:myapp/screens/login_screen.dart';`  use this remove `lib`

Comment: It worked thankyou! @lava. but I don't get where was my mistake...

Comment: lib folder is the root of the dart code .so you dont want import like that